# AutoHotKey: How do I set the starting value of the current loop iteration?

Tags: windows-7, script, automation, autohotkey, code

I've made a basic AHK script that adds unique metadata to each file on a system I use every day. The idea is to add _01 to the first file followed by _02 to the second file and going up forever until i exit the script.

At first, i felt like I've been doing this the long way and I wasn't sure what was required to make the script smaller and less painful to edit.

Here's the script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
F3::

 {
    Send, {LAlt}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 107, 30
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 346, 38
    Sleep, 200
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 100
    Send, _01
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    MouseClick, Left, 91, 102
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 92, 100
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 147, 156
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Down}



    Send, {LAlt}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 107, 30
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 346, 38
    Sleep, 200
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 100
    Send, _02
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    MouseClick, Left, 91, 102
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 92, 100
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 147, 156
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Down}



    Send, {LAlt}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 107, 30
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 346, 38
    Sleep, 200
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 100
    Send, _03
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    MouseClick, Left, 91, 102
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 92, 100
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 147, 156
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Down}



    Send, {LAlt}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 107, 30
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 346, 38
    Sleep, 200
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 100
    Send, _04
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    MouseClick, Left, 91, 102
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 92, 100
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 147, 156
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Down}



    Send, {LAlt}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 107, 30
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 346, 38
    Sleep, 200
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 100
    Send, _05
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    MouseClick, Left, 91, 102
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 92, 100
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 147, 156
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Down}

 }
```

So as you can see, I've had to copy/paste the entire script and change the _01 to be _02 in the next part, followed by _03, _04 and _05.

I found out how to do this with the use of **Loop** + **A_index** and it works fine just as the above does:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
F3::

Loop, 5

 {
    Send, {LAlt}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Right}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 107, 30
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Down}
    Sleep, 20
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 346, 38
    Sleep, 200
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 100
    Send, _
    Sleep, 100
    Send %A_Index%
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 200
    MouseClick, Left, 91, 102
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 92, 100
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 147, 156
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Down}


}
```

I now need to be able to *set the starting value* of %A_index% with the use of a input box at the beginning of the script.

I want to be able to enter any number into the inputbox and have %A_index% work sequentially *starting from that number*.

So since A_Index simply keeps track of the current loop iteration, and therefore is a built-in internal value that cannot be changed...

...what i'm essentially asking is:

**How do I get the script to start from a specific loop iteration using inputbox?**

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another intermediate variable, convert `A_Index` to a 0-indexed loop count by subtracting 1, and add them together inside the loop

```
InputBox, myEntry, Enter a value, Enter starting value...

Loop {
    myIndex:=myEntry + (A_Index-1)
    myIndex:=(myIndex<10) ? "0" myIndex : myIndex
    ;...
    Send %myIndex%
    ;....
}
```

Comment: Hi JJohnston2, I really appreciate your help there. Hoping you might have a workaround for one tiny issue i have with this. Is there a way to have it display 01 instead of 1 when sending %myindex%? Any chance you might be able to modify your answer if poss?

Comment: I'm referring to the first 9 values it sends which are 1-9 which I would need to be 01-09. Is that at all possible?

Comment: You can use the ternary operator ("?") to create a single If/Then statement.  i.e., If (myIndex<10) THEN put a "0" in front ELSE use as-is.  Technically you could combine both assignment statements into a single line, but that might be overly confusing

Comment: Ah i understand now. Thank you so much that's done the trick! Upvotes on everything mate!